# Sending email through PHP?

Tags: php, html

I havent used any PHP, and wanted to make a form on my html file send an email without using mailto:

I have looked online for some tutorials on how to do this, and the best I could do myself was this.

```
<form method="POST" action="contact.php">
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" size="24px"/> <input type="text" name="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" size="24px"/><br>
                <input type="tel" name="Phone" placeholder="Address" size="53px"/><br>
                <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Phone Number" size="53px"/><br>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" size="53px"/><br>
                <input type="email" name="confirmemail" placeholder="Confirm Email" size="53px"/><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submitButton" />
</form>
```

and for my PHP file the best I could try to get was this:

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
$recipient="basketgiftsreceiver@gmail.com";
$subject="Form to email message";
$sender=$_POST["Email sender"];
$senderEmail=$_POST["basketgiftssender@gmail.com"];
$message=$_POST["This is my message"];

$mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$message";

mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

$thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}

?>
```

When I click my submit button, all I get is this:

[image]

If any of you guys could help me with this, that help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a webserver? You need a server to run PHP scripts.

Comment: do you have to use a webserver? I am only running it locally.

Comment: grmackintosh - yes. Download and install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) to do PHP development on your Windows computer. Then come back and edit your question with any errors produced when you run your code.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of your issue you are not running a web server on localhost.

https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Php is server side scripting and does not run in the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts are only executed when you access them through a webserver. You can't use a local file to run a script. Accessing the script using `file://path` will just display the contents of the script, not run it.

Answer (score -1):

Beyond the fact that you probably not running a web server that supports php,

You are probably missing a smtp server, you need that to send an email in the code.
Google provides Information about their smtp.

server address : **smtp.gmail.com**

ports :
**465 (SSL required)** or **587 (TLS required)**